# R - Summarize dataframe to avoid NAs

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

Having a dataframe like:

```
id = c(1,1,1)
A = c(3,NA,NA)
B = c(NA,5,NA)
C= c(NA,NA,2)
df = data.frame(id,A,B,C)

  id  A  B  C
1  1  3 NA NA
2  1 NA  5 NA
3  1 NA NA  2
```

I want to summarize the whole dataframe in one row that it contains no NAs. It should looke like:

```
  id  A  B  C
1  1  3  5  2
```

It should work also when the dataframe is bigger and contains more ids but in the same logic.

I didnt found the right function for that and tried some variations of summarise().

Comment: Can columns of the same id have multiple non NAs? in this case, do you want sum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `group_by` id and use `max` with `na.rm = TRUE`:

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarise(across(everything(), max, na.rm = TRUE))

     id     A     B     C
1     1     3     5     2
```

---

If multiple cases, `max` may not be what you want, you can use `sum` instead.

Comment: I think they want sum?

Comment: Depends on the need, but this is possible. unclear

Comment: Yes, depends, maybe "coalesce" is what they need.

Answer (score 1):

Using `fmax` from `collapse`

```
library(collapse)
 fmax(df[-1], df$id)
  A B C
1 3 5 2
```

Comment: that's so cool!

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively please check the below code

```r
data.frame(id,A,B,C) %>% group_by(id) %>% fill(c(A,B,C), .direction = 'downup') %>% 
slice_head(n=1)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

```r
# A tibble: 1 × 4
# Groups:   id [1]
     id     A     B     C
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     3     5     2
```